# What is the operator "capital D" and how can the chain rule be used in this way

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

I ought to know this but I was somehow always able to avoid mixing partials and $d$s

My book notes the following: (with some intermediate steps which are less important than the time taken to write)

Here $f$ is a function of $x(t),y(t),z(t),t$ and $u=\frac{dx}{dt}$ and "" for others.

$\frac{Df}{Dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla)f$

I was taught to use $D$ for total derivative but there's no malformed interpretation I could apply here.

What is going on and if you were to look it up in an index of a book what would the book be on, and what would you look up? (E.G: Real analysis, partial differentiation)

Also I'm not sure how to use bold with LaTeX nor get a special dot. If someone could tell me in the comments I'd be very grateful.

Comment: That might be a case of a derivative seen from a moving particle or such.. I try to remember.

Comment: Bold is `\mathbf` and the dot is `\cdot`

Comment: @mvw It was a fluid dynamics book (well actually more than one)! So you're entirely right.

Comment: @mvw I meant to use the capital D for total derivative, I see a lot $D_tF$ for total derivative WRT t.

Comment: I have lately seen the big $D$ only for calculus of many variables.

Comment: You can assume $\frac{D}{Dt} = D_t$ here

Comment: @Omnomnomnom in that case I'm still not happy with the chain rule used this way and the Q stands

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I mean for example: "a simple application of the chain rule $\frac{Df}{Dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+...$ <-- where did this come from?

Answer (score 4):

***In the context of fluid/continuum mechanics, the operator $\frac{\mathrm{D}}{\mathrm{D}t}$ denotes the [material derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative). This is the sense in which $\mathrm{D}$ is being used in the equation you cite in your question.***

The material derivative is also often called the "total derivative", though that term is also [used in a completely different sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) in the context of multivariable calculus (specifically, it is the linear transformation described by the Jacobian matrix), which may be the source of your confusion.

---

In the study of fluid mechanics, there are [two perspectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field) from which a physical system is commonly analysed:

- the Eulerian perspective, which analyses the system in a fixed (e.g. Cartesian) coordinate system $(x, y, z)$, wherein we specify properties of the system at given locations, e.g. given a velocity vector field $\mathbf{u}(x, y, z, t)$, then $\mathbf{u}(2, 4, -7, 5)$ denotes the velocity of the flow at the point $(x, y, z) = (2, 4, -7)$ at time $t=5$.
- the Lagrangian perspective, which analyses what happens to given packets/corpuscles of fluid (called [fluid parcels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_parcel) in the literature) as the system evolves. Typically, we label each particle with its Eulerian coordinates at time $t=0$, and refer to that particle using that label at all times. The convention is to use uppercase variables $(X, Y, Z)$ to denote a Langrangian specification. For example, if a fluid parcel exists at the Eulerian position $(x, y, z) = (1, 3, 7)$ at time $t=0$, we can label that parcel $(X, Y, Z) = (1, 3, 7)$ permanently. As the fluid flow evolves over time, suppose that this parcel ends up at the Eulerian position $(x, y, z) = (2, 4, -7)$ at time $t=5$. If we denote the velocity of the parcel with Lagrangian label $(X, Y, Z)$ at time $t$ by $\mathbf{u}(X, Y, Z, t)$, then the quantity $\mathbf{u}(1, 3, 7, 5)$ (where the arguments are Lagrangian coordinates) describes precisely the same thing as the quantity $\mathbf{u}(2, 4, -7, 5)$ (where the arguments are Eulerian coordinates) mentioned in the previous bullet point. In  a given context, it should be clear whether the arguments passed to a function such as $\mathbf{u}$ are Eulerian or Lagrangian coordinates.

We can look at how any property of the system, such as the velocity $\mathbf{u}$ or the fluid density $\rho$, changes over time from either of these perspectives. With such a property denoted $\mathbf{F}$ in general, then:

- $\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{F}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ is the regular derivative, which describes how $\mathbf{F}$ changes over time as a function of Eulerian coordinates $(x,y,z)$.
- $\frac{\mathrm{D}\mathbf{F}}{\mathrm{D}t}$ is the material derivative, which describes how $\mathbf{F}$ changes over time as a function of Lagrangian coordinates $(X,Y,Z)$. Since it is the Lagrangian analogue of the Eulerian $\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{F}}{\mathrm{d}t}$, this is why the uppercase $\mathrm{D}$ is used to denote it, as per the previously mentioned convention.

If we want to express the material derivative in terms of Eulerian coordinates rather than Lagrangian coordinates, we [perform a coordinate transformation](https://youtu.be/xlxK0VuY9yY) from $(X,Y,Z)$ to $(x,y,z)$, which can be done using the chain rule by considering $\mathbf{F}$ for a specific fluid parcel as a function of time alone: the Lagrangian field $\mathbf{F}(t)$ for that specific fluid parcel becomes the Eurlerian field $\mathbf{F} \big( x(t), y(t), z(t), t \big)$, where $\big( x(t), y(t), z(t) \big)$ is a parameterisation of the trajectory of that fluid parcel. After applying the chain rule, everything is expressed in Eulerian coordinates, and we see that

$$\frac{\mathrm{D}\mathbf{F}}{\mathrm{D}t} \equiv \frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial t} + \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{F}.$$

---

The above identity is often expressed as

$$\frac{\mathrm{D}\mathbf{F}}{\mathrm{D}t} \equiv \frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial t} + (\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \: \mathbf{F},$$

which is the equation that you cite in your question, or as

$$\frac{\mathrm{D}\mathbf{F}}{\mathrm{D}t} \equiv \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \right) \mathbf{F},$$

or even simply as

$$\frac{\mathrm{D}}{\mathrm{D}t} \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla.$$

In all of these alternative ways of writing the identity, the term $\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla$ is a specific differential operator. Some consider $\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla$ to be abuse of notation, but regardless, it means the following: given

$$\mathbf{u}(x,y,z) \equiv \begin{pmatrix} u(x,y,z) \\ v(x,y,z) \\ w(x,y,z) \end{pmatrix},$$

then we have

$$\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \equiv u \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + w \frac{\partial}{\partial z},$$

so that

$$
\begin{align}
(\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \: \mathbf{F}
&\equiv \left( u \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + w \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \right) \mathbf{F} \\
&\equiv \enspace u \frac{\partial\mathbf{F}}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial\mathbf{F}}{\partial y} + w \frac{\partial\mathbf{F}}{\partial z} \\
&\equiv \enspace \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{F}.
\end{align}
$$

Importantly, the dot operator here is not commutative, so the differential operator $\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla$ should not be confused with the expression $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}$, which is the divergence of $\mathbf{u}$, and is given by

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} \equiv \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}.$$

Answer (score 3):

This is just the chain rule.  It may help to think of this as follows:

We have
$f = f(x(t),y(t),z(t),w(t))$ where it so happens that $w(t) = t$.  We then have
$$
\newcommand{\pwrt}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\dwrt}[2]{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
D_tf = \pwrt fw \dwrt wt  +
\pwrt fx \dwrt xt + 
\pwrt fy  \dwrt yt + 
\pwrt fz  \dwrt zt =\\
\pwrt fw + (\mathbf u \cdot \nabla)f
$$
you may consider rewriting $\pwrt fw$ as $\pwrt ft$ a slight abuse of notation.

Comment: That chain rule application is actually where I'm stuck. Could you elaborate about that please?

Comment: I've read the edit, but it's the actual chain rule part I'm not getting. Also mixing $d$s and $\partial$s, as I mention I've managed to avoid this entirely so far.

Comment: Have you seen any version of the chain rule for functions of several variables?  Perhaps something like $D(f \circ g) = Df Dg$? Maybe how to find $D(f \circ g)$ where $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ and $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$?

Comment: I've seen it but never used it. It gives me a place to start! To me the chain rule is as my maths teacher used to say "derivative of the bracket times the derivative of what's in the bracket"

Comment: All right. You're looking for the "multivariable chain rule".  I think you'll find [this explanation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx) to be reader-friendly.

Comment: A neat example to try: find the derivative of 
$$
f(t) = t^t
$$
by writing $f(x,y) = x^y$, $g(t) = (t,t)$, and $f(t) = f(g(t))$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I hope the 10 rep shows this!

Answer (score -1):

It's just the chain rule.

To be more precise, write $x=X(t)$, $y=Y(t)$, $z=Z(t)$ in order to distinguish the quantities $x$, $y$, $z$ from the functions $X$, $Y$, $Z$ which say how they depend on $t$. Now take your function $f(x,y,z,t)$ and define
$$
g(t) = f(X(t),Y(t),Z(t),t)
.
$$
Then the notation $Df/Dt$ (by definition) means exactly $g'(t)$, which can be computed using the chain rule:
$$
\begin{align}
g'(t) &= f'_x(X(t),Y(t),Z(t),t) \, X'(t) \\ &+ f'_y(X(t),Y(t),Z(t),t) \, Y'(t) \\ &+ f'_z(X(t),Y(t),Z(t),t) \, Z'(t) \\ &+ f'_t(X(t),Y(t),Z(t),t),
\end{align}
$$
which equals the given expression since $X'(t)=u$, etc.