# If $ y= x^{n-1}\log(x)$ , then prove that $D^n y $ is $ \frac{(N-1)!}{x}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[[image: If <span class=]$ y= x^{n-1} \log(x)$ , then prove that $D^n y $ is $  \frac{(N-1)!}{x}$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtXU5.jpg)

I don't understand this notation of "$D^n$".I searched it on internet and didn't got any useful information ([What is the operator "capital D" and how can the chain rule be used in this way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130328/what-is-the-operator-capital-d-and-how-can-the-chain-rule-be-used-in-this-way)) Please tell me what this notation stands for so that I can solve this question.

Comment: $D$ means $\frac{d}{dx}$. $D^n$ means $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$ ($n$-th derivative).

Comment: You can just attempt induction on each of the answers and see which work and which explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to understand $D^ny=\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$, you'll want to use [Leibniz's General Product Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(fg)=\sum_{k=0}^nC(n,k)(D^{n-k}f)(D^kg)$$

where $C(n,k)$ is a binomial coefficient, $f=x^{n-1}$, $g=\ln x$

Keeping in mind $D^p(x^n)=\frac{n!}{(n-p)!}x^{n-p}$ or $0$ if $p>n$.

Also note $D^p(\ln x)=\frac{(p-1)!(-1)^{p-1}}{x^p}$

Answer (score 2):

Usually $D^n y $ means $\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$.

$D$ is refers to the differential operator. Applying $n$ times means differentiate $n$ times.

Answer (score 2):

The exponent you are familiar with expresses "repeated multiplication by", like in

$$a^3\times b=a\times (a\times (a\times b))$$ ($b$ can be $1$).

By similarity, it is used to express "repeated application" of some operation, such as differentiation:

$$D^3f=D(D(Df)))=f'''.$$

In some contexts, it can be the repeated application of a function, like

$$\sin^3(x)=\sin(\sin(\sin(x))).$$

(Caution: can be confused with $(\sin(x))^3)$).

---

Now by induction,

$$D^{n+1}(x^n\log x)=D^n(D(x^n\log x))=D^n\left(nx^{n-1}\log x+\frac{x^n}x\right)=nD^n\left(x^{n-1}\log x\right).$$

The base case

$$D(\log x)=\frac1x$$ completes the proof.